# error handling using try and exception with condition in python

Tags: python

I have written an algorithm contains python codes.If the algorithm generates an error during the execution then basically it will try for every 10 seconds to run the same algorithm for 10 times...And after 10 times, still there is an error in the algorithm then it will throw an error message

The codes that i have written basically goes into some infinte loop and unable to execute the above logic. Can u help me out?

Heart is the main function containing the algorithm

```py
counter = 0
while counter < 10:

    try:
        currenttime = dt.datetime.now()
        if currenttime.hour % 1 == 0 :
            Heart()

    except:
        try:
            Heart()

            counter += 1
            time.sleep(10)
        except:
            print("Error,please check")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no question in your question ;) Could you please provide a description of your problem together with a [mcve]?

Comment: When the algorithm results in an infinite loop, it means the stop condition is never reached. If `Heart` is not raising an exception, `counter` is never incremented! On antother note, I don't understand `if currenttime.hour % 1 == 0 :`. What do you mean with this line?

Comment: means the heart() function will run every hour.....if there are errors in heart() function then it should retry executing heart() function again.